# Why does jQuery .html(string) shift the type attribute to the end of the input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with three different inputs; two text and one submit. The html for this form is stored in a javaScript variable `var form`. When the user clicks a button, the following code is executed:

```
$('#content').html(form);
```

This works as expected. Then, when the user clicks the button again, it compares the html of the `#content` element with `var form`. You would expect it to return true since I just set the element to contain the contents of form, yet it returns false.

I found that when I retrieve the html from the `#content` element, it's slightly different than it was when I inserted it. For each of the input tags, the `type` attribute is moved from the beginning to the end. That is:

```
<input type="text"... /> --> <input ...type="text" />
```

So understandably when I try to compare them, it returns false. However, that begs the question of why it isn't inserting the html exactly as it is in the variable?

Comment: This sound like the browser rearrange the order. Is out the same in all browsers?

Comment: Seems plausible. In both FF and Chrome it changes the html, although I can't verify if they change the same aspect(s). I mean I could verify but it's not that important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely not due to jQuery; this is the browser. Once text/html is turned into DOM nodes, turning those nodes back into text is browser-dependent and not defined by a spec.

If you want to compare if the contents of the `<form>` tag are the same as when you created it you can't compare its text form. After all, `<form class="foo" id="bar">` and `<form id="bar" class="foo">` would yield identical DOM nodes once parsed by a browser.

You should compare only the attributes you expect to change and have well-defined states, like the `value` of input elements.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. In that case, is there a particular reason why the browser would rearrange the type attribute to appear last in the input tag? When I find out this was the problem messing up my code, I became curious to find out why it occurs in the first place.

Comment: Attributes on a DOM node are represented by a Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.attributes Maps do not guarantee the order of their members like Arrays do. As long as all of the attributes are returned, regardless of their order, in the `.html()` call, it's a valid representation of what the browser knows about the DOM node.

Answer (score 1):

When `.html(form)` is executed, the browser makes changes to its underlying Document Object Model (DOM). It does not keep a record of the HTML that was passed as an argument.

Exactly the same is true of the HTML that forms a web page - after it has been interpreted into DOM nodes, the HTML itself plays no further part in the life of the page unless the page is refreshed.

The string string returned by `.html()` is totally **synthetic**.

So no, you would not expect the string returned by `.html()` to be identical to your original `form` variable.